# Updating data on Fragments in android

Tags: android, android-activity, realm, fragment, intentservice

I have a MainActivity that hosts two fragments in a tabview. A method on the MainActivity downloads data from a remote server using APIs and update a realm database using IntentService. This works fine. But, my problem is refreshing the data on the fragments after the download and database updates are completed. Do I need to restart the app itself? Any idea how I should do it?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        update();
        setFragment(new DrawFragment());

}
//method to download and update data
private void update(){
    if (!ActivityHelper.isDataAvailable()) {
                Log.d(CONST.TAG, "Data available. Updating to start...");
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyIntentService.class);
                intent.putExtra("message", "Some message here...");
                startService(intent);
    }    
}

public void setFragment(Fragment fragment){
        if(fragment!=null){
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.content_main, fragment);
            transaction.commit();
        }

        DrawerLayout drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RealmChangeListener` is what you are looking for here. It is given in [Realm Documentation.](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/)

> **Reuse RealmResults and RealmObjects**

On the UI thread and all other Looper threads, all RealmObjects and RealmResults are automatically refreshed when changes are made to the Realm. This means that it isn’t necessary to fetch those objects again when reacting to a RealmChangedListener. The objects are already updated and ready to be redrawn on the screen.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

private Realm realm;
private RealmResults<Person> allPersons;
private RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<Person>> realmListener = new RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<Person>>() {
    @Override
    public void onChange(RealmResults<Person> results) {
        // Just redraw the views. `allPersons` already contain the
        // latest data.
        invalidateView();
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    allPerson = realm.where(Person.class).findAllAsync(); // Create the "live" query result

    setupViews(); // Initial setup of views

    allPerson.addChangeListener(listener);
}

// ...
```